# Holomorphic and bijective function on B(0,1) is f(z) = $e^{i\theta}g_a(z)$ where $g_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if f: B(0,1) $\rightarrow$ B(0,1) is holomorphic and bijective, then there is some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in $B(0,1) such that f(z) = $e^{i\theta}g_a(z)$, where $g_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}$, which maps B(0,1) to B(0,1).

Previous parts of the question included proving Schwarz's lemma and then that if f(0)=0 and |f($z_0$)| = |$z_0$| for some $z_0 \in $B(0,1), $z_0 \neq$0, then f is a rotation.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655114/42969

Comment: Thank you so much